# Javascript Regex for multiple occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var text = "pgPag.append('<li><a title=\"' + __('First') + '\" href=\"#\">&lt;&lt;</a></li>');            pgPag.append('<li><a title=\"' + __('Previous') + '\" href=\"#\">&lt;</a></li>');  pgPag.append('<li><label>&nbsp;' + __('Page') + '&nbsp;</label><input type=\"text\" size=\"1\" /><label>&nbsp;</label></li>');           pgPag.append('<li><a title=\"' + __('Next') + '\" href=\"#\">&gt;</a></li>');            pgPag.append('<li><a title=\"' + __('Last') + '\" href=\"#\">&gt;&gt;</a></li>');";
var exp = '(?:(\'[a-z]*\'))';
var re = new RegExp(exp,["img"]);
var match = re.exec(text);
document.write(match);
```

Now how can I print string that starts like "__("  eg. "First","Previous","Page"
With the above code I can get only the first string i.e "First" and not the remaining strings.

Required Output :

First
Previous 
Page
Next
Last

Comment: For starters, `re.exec()` returns an array but you are treating it like a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

**One:** The second argument to `new RegExp(exp,["img"]);` needs to be a string, not an array. Therefore:

```
var re = new RegExp(exp, "img");
```

is what you are after. Or, better yet:

```
var re = /(?:('[a-z]*'))/img // This is a regular expression literal
```

**Two:** Like Mike said: use `text.match(re)` in order to get an array of matches from the whole string. `re.exec` will only give you one match at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var match = re.exec(text);
```

do

```
var matches = text.match(re);
```